# How can I disable rounded window corners in OS X

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there any way that the rounded window corners can be disabled in OS X Lion (10.7.3) ?

**Update:** It's the bottom two corners that I have problem with as they show up even in full screen mode.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm just curious anytime someone wants to change something that low-level in the system.

Comment: @CajunLuke I am doing cross OS screenshot comparison. And this issue makes the comparison fail as the screenshots look different on mac compared to the other OSes.

Comment: How are you doing the comparison? If you're doing pixel-for-pixel comparison, the close buttons (being different on OS X) would seem to also cause a problem.

Comment: @CajunLuke Pixel-by-pixel. The rest of the windowing ui is not a problem as it hides in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 7):

**Tested on 10.7.3 & 10.7.4**

---

To turn rounded corners off for all windows use the following command in Terminal.

```
defaults write -g AppleUseCoreUI -bool false ; killall Finder
```

To restore the rounded corners for all windows use the following command in Terminal.

```
defaults write -g AppleUseCoreUI -bool true ; killall Finder
```

**NOTE:** For this to take effect on already open applications those applications must be closed and reopened (this is why the commands above include **killall Finder**). *Some Applications may interact differently once CoreUI is turned off.*

**ALSO:** This does not affect the corners at the bottom of the window. They will still appear rounded. (As noted in comments by Daniel Lawson)

If you are not comfortable with the **killall Finder** being used in your command the steps can be taken to ensure the same result.

Step 1. (Turn **off** rounded corners)

- Run the following Command

  ```
  defaults write -g AppleUseCoreUI -bool false
  ```
- Remember to close and reopen any Applications that were open when prior to this command being run.

Step 2. (Turn **off** rounded corners)

- Refresh Finder

  Key combo **command** + **option** + **esc**... Choose **Finder** and click **Relaunch**
- Remember to close and reopen any Applications that were open when prior to this command being run.

To restore the original rounded corners, simply use the same 2 Steps and replace the  **false** found at the end of the command with **true** as shown in the following command.

```
defaults write -g AppleUseCoreUI -bool true
```

**Remember:** It is very likely that as you update your OS the rounded corners will reappear. However, even after your next OS update, the same steps listed above are likely to function the same. :–)

Comment: Neat find; I'd never heard of this before. When I tried this running 10.7.3, The bottom corners of the windows seem just as rounded as ever. The top corners did look different. Does this affect top and bottom corners differently?

Comment: I apologize, I hadn't ever really noticed, but the bottom corners do still appear to be rounded. :–( I have had my windows like this for a long time and never even noticed :-D **Editing** Answer to reflect.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question, it's exactly the bottom corners that I have problem with.

Comment: @Zitrax the following link might be helpful to you. http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=16805728 I do not have any experience using this nor do I know if all/any is functional above 10.6.x. Good luck, I wish I could be of more help.