# Can I change 10.8.2 Mountain Lion window corners from rounded to squared?

Tags: macos, ui, themes

Cosmetically I'd like all four corners of all OSX windows to be squared.

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50284/41317) proposed half-solution failed on Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

I *may* have seen a mod that was possible at [MacThemes forum](http://macthemes.net/forum/); alas I fail to recover any such thread.

How can I get corners on windows in Mountain Lion OSX 10.8.2 to be square instead of rounded?

Comment: I would recommend posting your solution as an answer to your own question here. This may help future users, and would allow you to mark this question as answered. It might be best to summarize when was said in the link, in case it breaks/moves in the future.

Comment: Of course, one reason of note people might consider before changing the appearance is that a rounded corner is a clear signal of a window border (as opposed to the edge possible being hidden beyond the monitor's edges or disguised among other windows).

Comment: @leoj3n, actually, per the [faq#reputation], "If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus." Thank you for posting your answer.

Comment: Any solution for 10.10?

Answer (score 2):

I found [a thread that describes how to accomplish the question asked](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=16812620&sid=d4104c73f36a2474823ec1bcc1d51d25).

To fix this I installed this artfile hack:

> This is just a simple artfile hack that removes rounded corners on windows, the fullscreen button, and replaces the standard traffic lights with the stiijo ones (that fade almost completely on background windows)
>
> I made it because I found it incredibly annoying to look at rounded corners when using my tiled window manager [xnomad](https://github.com/fjolnir/xnomad).
>
> Download: http://d.asgeirsson.is/obtv (Remember to back up your old (S)ArtFile !! This has only been tested on 10.8.2)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.