# macOS Mojave disable all 4 rounded window corners either with defaults, or software, or programatically

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there a system API, or utility (open source), or default I can set to disable all 4 rounded window corners on macOS?

I've checked the two other prominent questions relating to this:

1. [Can I change 10.8.2 Mountain Lion window corners from rounded to squared?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81313/can-i-change-10-8-2-mountain-lion-window-corners-from-rounded-to-squared)
2. [How can I disable rounded window corners in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50280/how-can-i-disable-rounded-window-corners-in-os-x?rq=1)

And the links are either dead, or the offered solution does not work.

Comment: I don't know for absolute certain, so can't provide an actual answer, but basically DIY custom theming hasn't been possible on Mac in the past decade.

Comment: I know that the radius is possible for NSWindowStyle or something to that effect, it seems a bit heavy if it is impossible to not change the window radius to 0 though :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, I used ThemeEngine to edit the appropriate theme in SystemAppearance.bundle.

I made a repo with the changes here: https://github.com/tsujp/custom-macos-gui

I know StackExchange hate linking answers so here is a summary for my case:

1. Using ThemeEngine edit the files in DarkAquaAppearance.car
2. The files you need to edit are WindowFrame_WindowShapeEdges
3. Change the masks to squares.
4. Change the base to completely transparent.
5. Reboot or otherwise restart the Dock, Finder, SystemUIServer, etc.

[image: img]

Comment: Care to add a screenshot? I'm curious how this looks.

Comment: @Dillon I added the screenshot in my repo to my self-answer, give it a check

Comment: This works great on Mojave, and also on Catalina. However, on Big Sur, I'm not able to find WindowFrame_WindowShapeEdges when I open the file in ThemeEngine. How can I fix the corners in Big Sur+?

Comment: I'm still waiting for my M1 machine to arrive at which point I can continue work on this and make a little single-binary configuration tool too. Until then I am not sure (no macOS machine to play around it, and VMs are a poor experience)

Comment: Is this working in Ventura? 